# java serial I/O: handling USB serial connection/disconnection in a robust manner

Tags: java, usb, serial-port, rxtx

I'm using [rxtx](http://rxtx.qbang.org) for serial I/O handling in Java with an FTDI2232H that provides a USB comm port. It works great, with one exception: if I unplug the USB cable, so that the COM port disappears at runtime, it spews exceptions left and right:

```
java.io.IOException: No error in nativeavailable
at gnu.io.RXTXPort.nativeavailable(Native Method)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialInputStream.read(RXTXPort.java:1427)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialInputStream.read(RXTXPort.java:1339)
```

and when I re-plug the cable in again, it does not recover.

Is there any way to get rxtx to work properly with USB comm port connection/disconnection? (I've tried to post to the rxtx mailing list but for some strange reason I cannot send messages even though I am subscribed to the list. I've emailed the list admin and have gotten no response.)

If not, is there another serial I/O framework that does?

Comment: Since running into this issue, I switched to [PureJavaComm](http://www.sparetimelabs.com/purejavacomm/purejavacomm.php) and have been using it for several years without any problems. I have abandoned use of RXTX; it's no longer well-maintained. [NRJavaSerial](https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial) is a maintained fork of RXTX -- haven't tried it in the last few years though.

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it, I do not know if this is possible in Java, but there is a windows message that gets broadcasted - [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(VS.85).aspx) message, it is likely you need to intercept this message and if it's a device eject, gracefully shut down the rxtx code. Here's an example [code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163503) to check for insertion/removal of CD in CDROM drive (It is not in Java).

**Edit:** Have added another link [here](http://www.steelbrothers.ch/jusb/api/usb/windows/related-docs/JavaUSBforWindowsWeb.pdf) that might be of interest to you.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

well. we use WM_DEVICECHANGE and coded in C++ and prepared DLL and then access it via JNI from JAva application.. so we get notification of connection and disconnection